# Unable to copy blobs from one container to another

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am creating a console app that copies all blobs in all containers from an account we use for production to another we use for development. I have the following method to do this. The 'productionStorage' and 'developmentStorage' objects are in another assembly where Azure storage client methods are housed.

```
    static void CopyBlobsToDevelopment()
    {
        // Get a list of containers in production
        List<CloudBlobContainer> productionBlobContainers = productionStorage.GetContainerList();

        // For each container in production...
        foreach (var productionContainer in productionBlobContainers)
        {
            // Get a list of blobs in the production container
            var blobList = productionStorage.GetBlobList(productionContainer.Name);

            // Need a referencee to the development container
            var developmentContainer = developmentStorage.GetContainer(productionContainer.Name);

            // For each blob in the production container...
            foreach (var blob in blobList)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = developmentContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
                targetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting an error (404) on the `targetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob()` line. But I don't understand why I'm getting a 404 error. The blob does exist in the source (production) and I want to copy it to the destination (development). Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please make sure that the ACL on source blob container is not Private. HTH.

Comment: @GauravMantri - Thank you. It is private. So do I need to provide credentials in the StartCopyFromBlob call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because the source blob container ACL is `Private`, what you would need to do is create a SAS Token (either on the blob container or on individual blobs in that container) with `Read` permission and append this SAS token to your blob's URL. Please see modified code below:

```
    static void CopyBlobsToDevelopment()
    {
        // Get a list of containers in production
        List<CloudBlobContainer> productionBlobContainers = productionStorage.GetContainerList();

        // For each container in production...
        foreach (var productionContainer in productionBlobContainers)
        {
            //Gaurav --> create a SAS on source blob container with "read" permission. We will just append this SAS
            var sasToken = productionContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
            });
            // Get a list of blobs in the production container
            var blobList = productionStorage.GetBlobList(productionContainer.Name);

            // Need a referencee to the development container
            var developmentContainer = developmentStorage.GetContainer(productionContainer.Name);

            // For each blob in the production container...
            foreach (var blob in blobList)
            {
                CloudBlockBlob targetBlob = developmentContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Name);
                targetBlob.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sasToken));
            }
        }
    }
```

I haven't tried running this code so please excuse me if you run into any errors with this code. But hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thank you. I will test this as soon as I have a chance.