# Is it possible to copy Azure CloudBlockBlobs between different Azure portal directories?

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I try to copy CloudBlockBlobs between different Azure portal directories/subsidiaries. So each Storage account belongs to a different directory/susbdiary.

When I try to copy the blobs I get a 404.

```
public class CopyBlobs
{
    private readonly CloudBlobClient _destClient;

    public CopyBlobs(ICloudBlobClientFactory cloudBlobClientFactory)
    {
        _destClient = cloudBlobClientFactory.CreateDestinationClient();
    }

    public async Task<List<CloudBlockBlob>> Process(CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory, string blobStorageId)
    {
        var blobs = new List<CloudBlockBlob>();

        var sourceBlobItems = blobDirectory.ListBlobs(true).OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();

        var destinationContainer = _destClient.GetContainerReference(blobStorageId);
        await destinationContainer.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        foreach (var sourceBlobItem in sourceBlobItems)
        {
            var exists = await sourceBlobItem.ExistsAsync(); // true

            var destinationBlobItem = destinationContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceBlobItem.Name);
            var b = await destinationBlobItem.ExistsAsync(); // false
            await destinationBlobItem.StartCopyAsync(sourceBlobItem.Uri); // 404

            blobs.Add(destinationBlobItem);
        }

        return blobs;
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Is it possible to copy Azure CloudBlockBlobs between different Azure portal directories?

Comment: I marked this as duplicate. While not 100% the same (the other question asks about PowerShell), the answer is effectively the same, as storage accounts are accessed via name+key, independent of subscription, or how it was created (classic vs ARM).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Can you help me why I get a StorageException with a 404 error?

Comment: Right answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30080749/175399